# useradd script not working as intended

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a script that allows a user to put information in a text file such as

```
Alice;McCormick;ballstate;2000;3457
```

using this format

```
FirstName;LastName;Password;UID;GID
```

---

```
import os
import hashlib
iFile = open(“NewUsers.txt”, “rt”)
fileContents = iFile.readlines()
Username =””
fname=””
lname=””
password=""
uid=""
gid=""

for line in fileContents:
    items = line.split(‘;’)
    fname = items[0].lower()
    lname = items[1].lower()
    username = fname[0]+lname[0:7]
    password = hashlib.sha256(items[2]).hexdigest()
    uid = items[3]
    gid = items[4]
    os.system("/usr/sbin/useradd -p " + password + " -u " + uid + " -g " + gid + username)
```

I created a group called 3000 that has a groupid of 3457 so it already exists.  When I run the script I get the following output.

Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
       useradd -D
       useradd -D [options]

Options: lists out all the available options you can use when doing useradd

below that I receive sh: 2: amccormi: not found

Comment: Consider putting your command line into a variable instead of passing it directly to `os.system`, and then printing that out to see what you have.  I think that will make your problem clear.

Comment: @larsks I have never saved a command line as a variable do you just save it as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have never saved a command line as a variable do you just save it as a string?

You're passing a string to `os.system`, so sure, you can just save that to a string:

```
cmd = "/usr/sbin/useradd -p " + password + " -u " + uid + " -g " + gid + username
```

And then you can print it out:

```
print "running command:", cmd
```

Before passing it to `os.system`:

```
os.system(cmd)
```

What you will find, ultimately, is that when you do this:

```
>>> iFile = open('data')
>>> fileContents = iFile.readlines()
>>> for line in fileContents:
...   items = line.split(';')
...   print items
```

The variable `items` will end up containing the following:

```
['Alice', 'McCormick', 'ballstate', '2000', '3457\n']
```

Look at the final item in that list, which is `3457\n`.  It contains a
newline character, which means when you build your command line like
this:

```
os.system("/usr/sbin/useradd -p " + password + " -u " + uid + " -g " + gid + username)
```

You end up passing the following to `/bin/sh`:

```
/usr/bin/useradd -p ballstate -u 2000 -g 3457
amccormi
```

Hopefully at this point it's clear why you're getting the error that
you've described.

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem.  The simplest is
probably to call `line.strip()`, which will remove whitespace
--including newlines -- at the beginning and end of your string:

```
>>> for line in fileContents:
...   items = line.strip().split(';')
```

Comment: Thank you that really helped seeing exactly what it was trying to input and not need to guess what changes needed to be made.